# Non-linear optics, non-linear polarization reference system?

Tags: optics, visible-light, electric-fields, non-linear-systems

in the Boyd's book about non-linear optics he defines the non-linear polarization for sum frequency generation, under particular symmetries, as

$$
\left[\begin{array}{c}
P_{x}(2 \omega) \\
P_{y}(2 \omega) \\
P_{z}(2 \omega)
\end{array}\right]=2 \epsilon_{0}\left[\begin{array}{llllll}
d_{11} & d_{12} & d_{13} & d_{14} & d_{15} & d_{16} \\
d_{21} & d_{22} & d_{23} & d_{24} & d_{25} & d_{26} \\
d_{31} & d_{32} & d_{33} & d_{34} & d_{35} & d_{36}
\end{array}\right]\left[\begin{array}{c}
E_{x}(\omega)^{2} \\
E_{y}(\omega)^{2} \\
E_{z}(\omega)^{2} \\
2 E_{y}(\omega) E_{z}(\omega) \\
2 E_{x}(\omega) E_{z}(\omega) \\
2 E_{x}(\omega) E_{y}(\omega)
\end{array}\right]
$$

what is the reference system of the electric field? Suppose that only the index $d_{36}$ is not zero (for example like in the GaAs) and the input electric field is linear polarized. Changing the reference system we can have zero or non zero non linear polarization. Why?

Comment: The reference system is that of the non-linear material, isn't it? Active optical materials break the relativity principle. Am I missing something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reference system is that of the crystal. Have a look for example at this document:

"Nonlinear Optics
Franz X. Kärtner and Oliver D. Mücke
Center for Free-Electron Laser Science, DESY
Department of Physics, University of Hamburg"
(of December 18, 2016)

and therein page 33. I think it is a nice argumentation how to figure out which elements will be zero.

Comment: Here is also the downloadlink: https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=&ved=2ahUKEwjewojE7_iDAxUa9QIHHeWBBXIQFnoECBMQAQ&url=https%3A%2F%2Fufox.cfel.de%2Fsites%2Fsites_cfelgroups%2Fsite_cfel-ufox%2Fcontent%2Fe16281%2Fe86791%2Fe86980%2Fe86982%2FinfoboxContent86984%2FManuscript_NLObis23122016.pdf&usg=AOvVaw3T1HWy7QZibLWU3eULpykP&opi=89978449